# Undefined variable error while extending the layouts

Tags: laravel

I have created a layout named front where the menu & footer are defined! The front layout contains the menu items from menu controller.

Here's my menu controller -

```
$menu = Menu::all();
/* some other long code */
```

Now i'm trying to extend the layouts using `@extends('front')` on posts page.

It returns the following error:

```
"Undefined variable: menus" in View: C:\xxxxx\layouts\front.blade.php.
```

I know it can be fixed by using `$menu = Menu::all();` in the posts controller also.

Since the application is huge & i can't keep pasting the menu controller code in every view that is extended.

> **How do i make the menu controller code global, so that whenever i extend the front layouts, it doesn't give me Undefined variable error ?**

Comment: Is this maybe a typo?  Your variable is `$menu` and your error is looking for `menus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use view composers to make a variable available to multiple views

In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` boot function

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(['first.view', 'second.view', 'another.view'], function ($view) {
        return $view->with('menus', App\Menu::all());
    });
}
```

And to make the variable available everywhere, use the `*` wildcard instead

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
        return $view->with('menus', App\Menu::all());
    });
}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Watch the @Watercayman's comment under your question..
But I think the thing that you want is below:

You need to show your variable in the blade where you didn't sent from controller.
In this kind of situations you can use "share" functionality from "Illuminate\Support\Facades\View".
You can just share your variable from main Controller's constructor (this can be as "App\Http\Controllers\Controller", or other as well if it takes care for all pages which uses $menu), like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function __construct()
{
    // here you can write some global things for all controllers which extending from this
    $menu = Menu::all();
    View::share('menu', $menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this variable is only needed by a layout, you can use a view composer for the layout to pass the variable you need.

```
// a service provider @ boot

View::composer('layouts.front', function ($view) {
    $menus = Menu::all();
    ...
    $view->with('menus', $menus);
});
```

[Laravel 6.0 Docs - Views - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers)